# How to split a file

Tags: python, awk

I have text file in this format:

```
10900   PART1   3211034
10900   PART2   3400458
10900   PART4   3183857
10900   PART3   4152115
10900   PART5   3366650
10900   PART6   1548868
10920   PART3   4154075
10920   PART2   3404018
10920   PART1   3207571
10920   PART4   3178505
10920   PART6   1882924
10920   PART5   3363267
10940   PART6   2183534
10940   PART3   4153924
10940   PART4   3178554
10940   PART1   3207436
10940   PART5   3363585
10940   PART2   3404220
```

And I want to split the file - first, by first column; and second, by the summation of column 3 not greater than 10000000.

Here's my code to split file base on first Column:

```
file1=open ('Normal_All_TracNum_mod')
data=[]

for line in file1.readlines():
line_split=line.split()
data.append(line_split)

RCV_check= data[0][0]
filewrite=open(RCV_check,"w")

for i in range(0,len(data)):
    if (data[i][0] == RCV_check):
        filewrite.write(data[i][0]+ "          "+data[i][1]+'\n')

    else:
        RCV_check=data[i][0]
        filewrite.close()
        filewrite=open(RCV_check,"w")
        filewrite.write(data[i][0]+ "          "+data[i][1]+'\n')   
filewrite.close()
```

Output As I want:

```
File 1
 10900  PART1   3211034
 10900  PART2   3400458
 10900  PART4   3183857
File 2
 10900  PART3   4152115
 10900  PART5   3366650
 10900  PART6   1548868
...etc
```

I need in each file has same column One And Summation (3211034 +3400458 + 3183857) of column 3 not greater than 10000000 and so on for other files.............

Comment: please finish your sentence "At the end I…"

Comment: I don't understand your question. How do you want to split the columns and what is the criterion for determining which lines get written to which file?

Comment: i'm not really getting the logic of the division..why in file 2 you still have a path1 object? didn't you want to separate them in different files?

Comment: first criter is first colume and second one the second colume does not excee x number in each file ..... Summation for second colume does not excee x number ,,, I hope this make it clear ...

Comment: awk soultion is welcome also ..

Comment: Real file look like this :10900 PART1 3211034
10900 PART2 3400458
10900 PART4 3183857
10900 PART3 4152115
10900 PART5 3366650
10900 PART6 1548868
10920 PART3 4154075
10920 PART2 3404018
10920 PART1 3207571
10920 PART4 3178505
10920 PART6 1882924
10920 PART5 3363267
10940 PART6 2183534
10940 PART3 4153924
10940 PART4 3178554
10940 PART1 3207436
10940 PART5 3363585
10940 PART2 3404220
I want to split base on First Colume and Summtion of second colume not greater than 10000000.

Comment: of thrid coulme is not greater than 10000000 .... sorry for miss write.

Comment: don't try to put formatted text in a comment as it won't work, just edit your original post if there's something more to tell, which it looks like there is.

Comment: I understand the the sum of the second column should not be greater than 10000000. What is the condition on the first column?

Comment: Sorry This is My first Post in this Website ... still not familar how it is work ....

Comment: We're here to help (don't worry about this being your first post), but can't do so without a well defined question. What do you want to do with the first column. If you are not able to explain it clearly, please post sample input and the expected output

Comment: I can do it by creat 2 script , The first One Split by first Colume The second One split by summation of thrid coulm not greather than xxxxxxxxxx .... I want to do Only One script for 2 condition....

Comment: Thank you for every one ...... It is solve .

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way using `awk`:

```
awk '{ s+=$3 } s>=10000000 || $1!=x { s=$3; c++ } { print > "File" c; x=$1 }' file
```

This creates 7 files. Here's the output of `grep . File*` showing the contents of each of these files:

```
File1:10900   PART1   3211034
File1:10900   PART2   3400458
File1:10900   PART4   3183857
File2:10900   PART3   4152115
File2:10900   PART5   3366650
File2:10900   PART6   1548868
File3:10920   PART3   4154075
File3:10920   PART2   3404018
File4:10920   PART1   3207571
File4:10920   PART4   3178505
File4:10920   PART6   1882924
File5:10920   PART5   3363267
File6:10940   PART6   2183534
File6:10940   PART3   4153924
File6:10940   PART4   3178554
File7:10940   PART1   3207436
File7:10940   PART5   3363585
File7:10940   PART2   3404220
```

Comment: `cat File*` seems more natural than `grep . File*` to show the contents of the files.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: Thanks mate. Unfortunately, I don't think `cat` shows the filename?

Answer (score 0):

If I get your specification correctly, the bellow might work for you. Basically it checks if the second field is greater than 1000 and if so prints it to `filec` (`c` is the counter) then resets the sum of the second fields and increments the file counter, etc.

```
awk 'BEGIN {c=1}
     $3>10000000 {print $0 > ("file" c) ; c++ ; sum=0 } 
     $3< 10000000 {print $0 > ("file" c) ; sum+=$3 ; if (sum> 10000000) {sum=0;c++}}' INPUTFILE
```

If you want to split on the first columnd *and* on the sum of the third columnd:

```
awk 'NR==1 {f=$1; c=1 ; fname=f c ; s=$3 ; print $0 > (fname)}
     NR>1  {if ($1 != f) {f=$1 ; c=1 ; fname=f c; s=$3 } } 
     NR>1  {if (s<10000000) {print $0 > (fname); s+=$3} else {c++;fname=f c;s=$3; print $0 > (fname)} }' INPUTFILE
```

And yeah, I know that this can be shortened...

Comment: You seem to be doing extra work: `awk 'BEGIN {c=1} {sum+=$3; if (sum > 10000000) {sum=0; c++}; print > FILENAME"."c}'`

Comment: Yep, that was my first thougt @glennjackman but the question specifies as "I need in each file has same colume One And Summation (3211034 +3400458 + 3183857) of Colume 3 not greather than 10000000 and so on for othrt files............." (and it was edited several times...)

Comment: Answer corrected, it works correctly now. A minor tip @Majid read the FAQ @ http://stackoverflow.com/faq and if an answer is helpful upvote it, and if it's solves your problem, accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you want to do with the first column. But, here's some python that respects the constraint on the sum of the second column

fileID = itertools.count(1)
with open('path/to/file')  as infile:
    sum = 0
    threshold = 10000000
    outfile = open("file%d"%fileID, 'w')

```
for line in infile:
    val = int(line.strip().split()[-1])
    if threshold-sum >= val:
        outfile.write(line)
    else:
        outfile.close()
        sum = 0
        outfile = open("file%d"%next(fileID), 'w')
        outfile.write(line)

    sum += val

outfile.close()
```

Hope this helps